# unity 3d installation issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to install unity 3d (5.4.2) software (64 bit version). everything is downloaded and installed as per the instructions, but it does not open. It just shows a blank screen. Please check out the screen shot attached below.

I don't know if this is relevant here but my laptop specifications are- win 10- 64 bit, 2GB AMD graphics, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD. I think it should work on this laptop!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Found your issues in this thread:

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity3d-5-3-not-working.372682/

**Sovlution:**

1. Found packages **unityeditor-cloud-hub-0.0.1.tgz** and
   **unity-editor-home-0.0.7.tgz** in C:\Program
   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Resources\Packages.
2. Create new folders **node_modules\unityeditor-cloud-hub** and
   **node_modules\unity-editor-home** in
   C:\Users\%user_name%\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages.
3. Extract **dist and package.json** from unityeditor-cloud-hub-0.0.1.tgz
   into unityeditor-cloud-hub, **dist and package.json** from
   unity-editor-home-0.0.7.tgz into unity-editor-home.

Comment: Hi the last folder that i can see is the packages folder and it only contains a file named 'package.json'.

Comment: Good job @ArpitBanjara , I can comment in your post, i am new in the overstack.

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer on the unity forum link that you provided and now it works

this what to do
I found packages unityeditor-cloud-hub-0.0.1.tgz and unity-editor-home-0.0.7.tgz in C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Resources\Packages. Create folders node_modules\unityeditor-cloud-hub and node_modules\unity-editor-home in C:\Users\%user_name%\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Packages. Extract dist and package.json from unityeditor-cloud-hub-0.0.1.tgz into unityeditor-cloud-hub, dist and package.json from unity-editor-home-0.0.7.tgz into unity-editor-home.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could be from a bug in 5.4.2f1 installer:

> An issue was discovered with performing a clean install of Unity 5.4.2f1 onto a Windows PC; if installed into a path containing spaces, Unity would fail to launch the Home window correctly

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-patch-releases.246198/page-3#post-2823574